# Graph reputation across all sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, graphs

In select places on Area51 you can see your total reputation, and on each SE site you can see a temporal graph of your reputation for that site. Is there any way to see a temporal graph of your total reputation across all sites?

Comment: I was just thinking about this exact item yesterday. It would be nice.

Comment: That could be an interesting feature addition to Rep Compare.  It's a little Java program I wrote to compare your reputation with others across all sites. - http://code.google.com/p/se-reputation-compare/

Comment: Where are the "select places" in Area51 where you can see you total reputation ?

Comment: @Ralph Off the top of my head, I can remember that it is shown on pages of sites you're committed to. I've seen it in other places as well, but I can't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see a graph of you reputation on all sites where you have over 200 reputation from your global Stack Exchange profile:

[image]

This one's mine, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible from a purely technical standpoint, but I doubt that implementing it would be worth the effort it would take. The "combined flair" can be fun to look at — wow, look how much bigger that number is than any of my individual site reputations! — but it doesn't have a huge amount of meaning.

Stack Overflow reputation points and Seasoned Advice reputation (and rep from other sites) are like apples and oranges (and bananas and hawthorns and mangoes and pitayas). It's hard enough to compare two apples to each other, let alone two crates of mixed fruit.

Going from a simple total sum to a graph just adds more information that has little actual significance.

Comment: I agree with you to some extent that rep from the different sites is not all the same. But apparently combined rep is important enough to Area51's operation to be used all over that site. I imagine a commitment from somebody with several thousand rep from several different sites is worth more than somebody with 51 rep just at Area51. So I don't necessarily agree that it's only "fun to look at" and that it has "little actual significance."

Comment: @Daniel, okay, that's fair. I don't visit A51 much, and didn't know how significant the figure was. I'm still not sure what useful info the graph would provide that the total score doesn't already provide, though. It doesn't look like A51 cares when or how steadily you earned your rep.